# Error: Contract with a Signer cannot override from (operation="overrides.from", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=contracts/5.6.0)

Tags: solidity, hardhat

This is the solidity function that I have written,

```
function jobAssignment(uint256 _jobID) external {
        //Require the job to be pending
        Job memory job = JobList[_jobID];
        require(
            job.jobStatus == JobStatus.PENDING,
            "This job is already accepted by a freelancer"
        );
        // Assign freelancer to job
        job.freelancer = msg.sender;
        // Change status of job
        job.jobStatus = JobStatus.IN_PROGRESS;
        // emit event
        emit JobAssigned(_jobID, msg.sender);
    }
```

I am using hardhat and trying to run a test on this function as follows,

```
describe("Job assignment to freelancer", function () {
    before(async function () {
    [jobOwner, freelancer] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
      jobContract.createJob("Job2", ethers.utils.parseEther("1"), {
        from: jobOwner.address,
      });
    });
    it("Should emit event of job assignment", async function () {
      await jobContract.jobAssignment(2, {
        from: freelancer.address,
      });
      
    });
  });
```

jobOnwer is the one who deployed the contract and create the specific job in the test script. Now I want to call the function with the freelancer. But this error comes up

`Error: Contract with a Signer cannot override from (operation="overrides.from", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=contracts/5.6.0)`

These are the Dev dependecies,

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.5",    
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.3",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.4",
    "ethers": "^5.6.4",
    "hardhat": "^2.9.3",
    "web3": "^1.7.3"
  }
```

Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

await jobContract.connect(freelancer).jobAssignment(2)

For more reference refer to this https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts.html
under "Using a different account" topic